# GCM push notification not received from the backend

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm working on a new app that includes push notifications. Here is what i've done till now:

```
public class C2DMMessageReceiver extends IntentService {
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
private final String TAG = "GCM Notification receiver..";
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

public C2DMMessageReceiver() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
    // in your BroadcastReceiver.
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
        /*
         * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM
         * will be extended in the future with new message types, just ignore
         * any message types you're not interested in, or that you don't
         * recognize.
         */
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                    extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            // This loop represents the service doing some work.
            for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                        + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            // Post notification of received message.
            sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
            Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
        }
    }
    // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
    C2DMRegistrationReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

// Put the message into a notification and post it.
// This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
// a GCM message.
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("עדכוני TGSpot")
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(msg))
                    .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
}
```

This is the code that handles the receiving of the data from the GCM from my third-party server backend codes.

The tokens of the devices are saved successfully on the server, they pushed to the server by regular HTTP Post request.

Here is the Android manifest:

```
    <permission android:name="com.tgspot.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.tgspot.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <receiver
        android:name=".C2DMRegistrationReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" >
            </action>

            <category android:name="com.tgspot.android" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".C2DMMessageReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <activity
        android:name="com.tgspot.android.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The C2DMRegistrationReceiver.class

```
public class C2DMRegistrationReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.w("C2DM", "Registration Receiver called");

    if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION".equals(action)) {
        Log.w("C2DM", "Received registration ID");
        final String registrationId = intent
                .getStringExtra("registration_id");
        String error = intent.getStringExtra("error");

        Log.d("C2DM", "dmControl: registrationId = " + registrationId
                + ", error = " + error);
        String deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        sendRegistrationIdToServer(deviceId, registrationId);
        // Also save it in the preference to be able to show it later
        saveRegistrationId(context, registrationId);
    } else if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE".equals(action)) {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                C2DMMessageReceiver.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}

private void saveRegistrationId(Context context, String registrationId) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.putString("C2DMM_AUTH", registrationId);
    edit.commit();
}

public void sendRegistrationIdToServer(String deviceId,
                                       String registrationId) {


    Log.d("C2DM", "Sending registration ID to my application server");
    final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    final HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.tgspot.co.il/register/");

    // set up the POST data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    // Get the deviceID
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("os", "Android"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token",
            registrationId));

    // encode the POST data
    try {
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        //e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    // execute the HTML POST call to hit the server
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you show the code of `C2DMRegistrationReceiver`?

Comment: @Eran it's still not working. i'm very thankful for your patient. Any more ideas?

Comment: Does your server get a successful response,  with an id? Do you see anything in the device's logcat when you send the message?

Comment: @Eran there are no errors when i'm sending a push. The key api from the GCM is the Server Key - am i right? the logcat attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your manifest you are missing `<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />`
 is the intent-filter of `C2DMRegistrationReceiver`. Without it a GCM message broadcast can't reach the app.

You haven't included the permissions section of the manifest in the question, so I can't say if you are missing other things.

Your `C2DMRegistrationReceiver` handles only REGISTRATION intents. It should also handle `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE`. Those are the intents that receive the GCM messages.

Actually C2DMRegistrationReceiver doesn't have to handle REGISTRATION intents at all if you are using the new synchronized registration approach with GoogleCloudMessaging.register (and I see you are already using that class).

Your `onReceive` method should be changed to :

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.w("C2DM", "Registration Receiver called");

    if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION".equals(action)) {
        Log.w("C2DM", "Received registration ID");
        final String registrationId = intent
                .getStringExtra("registration_id");
        String error = intent.getStringExtra("error");

        Log.d("C2DM", "dmControl: registrationId = " + registrationId
                + ", error = " + error);
        String deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        sendRegistrationIdToServer(deviceId, registrationId);
        // Also save it in the preference to be able to show it later
        saveRegistrationId(context, registrationId);
    } else if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE".equals(action)) {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                C2DMMessageReceiver.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

This way a `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE` broadcast would trigger the `C2DMMessageReceiver` service, which displays the notification.

And if you are using the new registration approach, the first if condition is not necessary at all.

Comment: thanks for your answer. looks like it's still not working. I've added the permissions section to the post.

Comment: @DanielChernenkov Why do your *.permission.C2D_MESSAGE permission start with `com.xxx.android`? It should start with your package name (which I assume, from elsewhere in your manifest, is `com.tgspot.android`)

Comment: oh yea, the xxx was the tgspot. it's ok.